# ¿Se puede heredar un activity en Android Studio / Java?

Tags: java, android, herencia

Necesito heredar las funciones y el apartado gráfico de un activity en Android Studio, necesito hacer muchos más activities con el mismo formato con la diferencia de que cambiaré el nombre de la "Actividad", sin embargo, al momento de heredar la clase suceden dos cosas, los métodos no los puedo utilizar y la parte gráfica no se muestra en el editor de Android Studio, ¿Qué puedo hacer?.

PD: La herencia como tal, funciona, pero no puedo editarla de ninguna manera, además, el encapsulamiento está bien hecho.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Por qué no usas esa misma Activity para todo lo que quieres hacer con las otras que heredarían de ella?

Comment: Si se puede, agrega imagenes e informacion que sea legible para la comunidad para de esta forma pueda ayudarte de mejor manera, recuerda revisar [ask], saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buen día @michel. La herencia de actividades no es muy complicada en Android Studio, y te permite evitar la duplicación de código. Puedes utilizarla de varias formas en dependencia de lo que buscas. Por ejemplo:
Si tienes dos actividades diferentes y en cada una necesitas implementar un método en común (por ejemplo una animación), puedes heredar dichas actividades a una clase padre, que extienda a su vez a activity, luego declararas el método en esa actividad, debe tener como modificador de acceso public o protected (te sugiero usar protected siempre y cuando puedas para mantener el encapsulamiento propio de lenguaje) y por último llamar al método desde cualquier parte de las dos actividades. Por ejemplo:
Main.java

```
public class Main extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    protected void cambiarTransparencia(View view) {
        Animation animation = new AlphaAnimation(0f, 1f);
        animation.setDuration(5000);
        view.startAnimation(animation);
    }
}
```

Activity1.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.msomnium.herencia.Activity1">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="Activity1" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Activity1.java

```
public class Activity1 extends Main {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_1);

        final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                cambiarTransparencia(button);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Activity2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.msomnium.herencia.Activity2">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Activity2.java

```
public class Activity2 extends Main {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_2);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        cambiarTransparencia(imageView);
    }
}
```

Ahora si a lo que te refieres en la pregunta es a implementar varias actividades con el mismo diseño gráfico no estarías utizando la herencia, sino reutilizar el mismo diseño xml para varias actividades. Por ejemplo: si tienes varias actividades con el mismo diseño gráfico, o con diseños gráficos semejantes, puedes crear un solo archivo xml con el diseño, y luego, cuando llames al método setContentView() le pasas como argumento el xml. Por ejemplo:

graphic_design.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="Diseño Común" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Activity1.java

```
public class Activity1 extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.graphic_desing);
    }
}
```

Activity2.java

```
public class Activity2 extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.graphic_desing);
    }
}
```

De esta forma al lanzar Activity1 o Activity2 ambas tendrían el mismo diseño gráfico, el cual podrás cambiar como tu quieras. Tambén puedes utlizar las dos soluciones en conjunto, siempre y cuando se adapten a tu proyecto. Espero haber aclarado tus dudas con respecto a la herencia de actividades en Android Studio.

Comment: Era exactamente lo que buscaba, me sirvió mucho, gracias!